# how to write query to get teacher_name in table2 by splitting values of teacher_id in table1

Tags: mysql, sql, select, database-design

here is my table2
table 1

```
1. #student_id   #student_name   #teacher_id
----------------------------------------
2.  5396           aswin          5975,6266,5977,5978
```

table 2

```
1. #teacher_name   #teacher_id
-----------------------------------
1. vijay              1011
2. syam               5975
3. andrew             5977
5. laxman             5467
6. max                6756
```

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Use your client language to "split()" or "explode()" the data.

Plan B:  Write a Stored Procedure to simulate such.  I cringe at the thought of how clumsy that code will be.